# Search and Replace href URL in Microsoft Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have embedded links in many Microsoft Word documents that point to the wrong URL.  These links all have specific titles like "Click Here" etc.  So I need to fix the href URL and I want to do it through VBA.  Basically I need to do a search and replace that looks at href URLs.

Example: [Click Me](http://yahoo.com) needs to be change to [Click Me](http://google.com)

I know how to do a search and replace on text in a Word Document. What I can't figure out is how to update an href URL that isn't actually text on the page.

Comment: Word documents have a Hyperlinks collection - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192421.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each link in ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    link.Address = Replace(link.Address, "yahoo", "google")
Next
```

Comment: Awesome.  This is exactly what I needed.  Works perfectly  Thanks for the quick turnaround.